# how to match two instances and replace the first one using regular expression in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace only the first instance if two matches returned.

example:

```
$sen = "The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog, fox is quick";
```

how can i match only the first **fox** and replace it with wolf and vice versa.

Output:

```
The quick brown wolf jump over the lazy dog, fox is quick
```

or:

```
The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog, wolf is quick
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was with you all the way up to "and vice versa".

Comment: vice versa means if i want to replace only the second instance.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly two instances, or should the substitution occur if there are more than two?

Comment: Yeah, I know. Perhaps your question should have been "...and replace only one of them".

Comment: @ikegami - it can be more than two. and please can you show me better way to match and count the instances.

Comment: @aliocee, Add answer to this new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting matches by using global option `/g`, assign list of matches to an empty list to get a count (better than a temp variable). First replace is basic. Second uses a counter that increments for each match, and replaces at the proper time.

Note use of word border `\b` to prevent false matches, such as `firefox`, `foxy lady`, etc.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;   # only required for say, use print instead if your version is lower

my $fox  = 'fox';
my $wolf = 'wolf';
my $sen = "The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog, fox is quick";

if ((()=$sen =~ /\b$fox\b/g) == 2) {   # counting matches 
    my $first = $sen;
    $first =~ s/\b$fox\b/$wolf/;       # replacing first
    my $second = $sen;
    my $i = 0;
    $second =~ s/\b$fox\b/ ++$i == 2 ? $wolf : $fox/eg;  # replacing second
    say for $first, $second;
}
```

**Output:**

```
The quick brown wolf jump over the lazy dog, fox is quick
The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog, wolf is quick
```

If you wish a more reusable code, you can make a subroutine out of it.

```
my $second = replace_nr($sen, $fox, $wolf, 2);
...
sub replace_nr {
    my ($str, $find, $replace, $num) = @_;
    my $i = 0;
    $str =~ s/\b($find)\b/ ++$i == $num ? $replace : $find/eg;
    return $str;
}
```

You could then even use the sub for both substitutions:

```
my $first  = replace_nr($sen, $fox, $wolf, 1);
my $second = replace_nr($sen, $fox, $wolf, 2);
```

Comment: @aliocee Yes you can. But it will not replace anything if there are not 3 matches.

Comment: at TLP: Can my match string contain fox|dog to be replace with wolf?

Comment: @aliocee It can, but then you'd need to surround `$find` with parens, i.e. `s/\b($find)\b/...`

Answer (score 2):

To check if there are (at least) two and replace the first:

```
# The quick brown *wolf* jump over the lazy dog, fox is quick
s/fox(?=.*fox)/wolf/s;
```

To check if there are (at least) two and replace the second:

```
# The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog, *wolf* is quick:
s/fox.*\Kfox/wolf/s;

s/(fox.*)fox/${1}wolf/s;  # Slower, but works pre 5.10
```

Comment: Thanks, the instances can be more than two, please can you suggest a better way of matching the instance for me?

Comment: @aliocee, "the instance" makes no sense if there are three instances.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the substitution operator does exactly that: match and replace the first occurence.

The following statement will get you your first output line:

```
s/wolf/fox/
```

Comment: what about if i want to match the second first?

Comment: @aliocee well, you'd have to find another pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your new question is that you want the count

```
my $count = () = $text =~ /fox/g;
```

and to replace the Nth instance

```
my $n = 3;
my $nm1 = $n-1;
$text =~ s/(?:fox.*){$nm1}\Kfox/s;
```